# Add JSP code to HTML div tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

How can I replace div content with JSP code using jQuery?

I tried the below code but it shows me nothing.

html:

```
<ul class="list-group" id="menuList">
<li id="dashboard" class="list-group-item active">&nbsp;
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home">&nbsp;</span>
    Dashboard
</li>
<li id="users" class="list-group-item">&nbsp;
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">&nbsp;</span>
    Users
    <span class="badge">5</span>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item">&nbsp;
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks">&nbsp;</span>
    Tasks
    <span class="badge">0</span></li>
<li class="list-group-item">&nbsp;
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list">&nbsp;</span>
    Articles
    <span class="badge">0</span>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item">&nbsp;
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog">&nbsp;</span>
    Settings
</li></ul>

<div class="col-md-10 col-centered" id="content"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#menuList > li").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass(" active");
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
    $("#content").html("<jsp:include page=\"users.jsp\" />");
});
```

Comment: Where is the element menuList? or add a jsfiddle

Comment: i added the menuList code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: You didn't close the brackets properly.

```
<ul class="list-group" id="menuList">
<li id="dashboard" class="list-group-item active">&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home">&nbsp;</span>Dashboard</li>
<li id="users" class="list-group-item">&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">&nbsp;</span>Users<span class="badge">5</span></li>
<li class="list-group-item">&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks">&nbsp;</span>Tasks<span class="badge">0</span></li>
<li class="list-group-item">&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list">&nbsp;</span>Articles<span class="badge">0</span></li>
<li class="list-group-item">&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog">&nbsp;</span>Settings</li></ul>

<div class="col-md-10 col-centered" id="content"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menuList > li").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass(" active");
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#content").html("<jsp:include page='users.jsp' />");
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: it's working now, but when i put the jquery code in external file it's not working, i tried to change the path name and got the same result,

Comment: Where you included the js file in html page?

Comment: yes, i have two folders "Admin" and "javascript" , i have users.jsp inside Admin folder, and the jquery code in javascript folder

Comment: Try replacing 'users.jsp' with '../Admin/users.jsp' in include statement.